# How to move a scale a label that is overlaid onto a picturebox as the form resizes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I would like to be able to re-size my form and have everything scale with it.  For example, if the form gets bigger, all the objects (including font) gets bigger, BUT STAYS IN ITS RELATIVE SPOT.

I have a bunch of labels that are placed on a picture box.  The picture box is a floor layout and the labels are objects on that floor layout.  I want to be able to change the labels different colors as well as their respective text to signal something is going on, this is why I decided to go this route

Here's what I have tried:

```
    WidthDiff = (PictureBox1.Width - OldWidth) / 2
    HeightDiff = (PictureBox1.Height - OldHeight) / 2

    '  MsgBox("WidthDiff: " & WidthDiff & "       HightDiff: " & HeightDiff & "       OldWidth: " & OldWidth)


    For Each lbl As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
        lbl.Size = New Size(Me.ClientSize.Width / 15, Me.ClientSize.Height / 15)
        lbl.Location = New Point(lbl.Location.X + WidthDiff, lbl.Location.Y + HeightDiff)
        lbl.Font = New Font("Arial", Me.ClientSize.Height / 100)
        Next

    ' PictureBox1.Size = New Size(Me.ClientSize.Width - 10, Me.ClientSize.Height - 30)



    OldHeight = PictureBox1.Height
    OldWidth = PictureBox1.Width
```

The problem with this is that though the labels, fonts, and picture scales, the labels don't stay in the same spot on the picture box floor layout.  I have endlessly tried to adjust the values but have no luck.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: It looks like you should set the .Location of each Label as a proportion of PictureBox1.Width and PictureBox1.Height.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: How were the labels positioned to get them in the correct places initially?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I positioned them on the designer and drag and drop

Comment: You could try getting all their positions in the Form load handler. Work them out relative to the location of the picture box. Then when the form is resized, you can scale their locations according to the scale of the picture box and add on the offset of the picture box's new location.